# Apostrophe cms: To edit global settings is further setup required beyond what is mentioned in the tutorial?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Followed this tutorial (http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/settings.html). No errors and the Global item is added to the menu bar but the modal is empty.

lib/modules/apostrophe-global/index.js

```
module.export = {
    addFields: [
        {
            type:'string',
            name:'analytics',
            label: 'Google Analytics Property ID (like UA-XXXXX)'
        }
    ]
};
```

The rest of the site so far is essentially vanilla, I have installed the workflow module (which seems to work fine) but otherwise thats it.

Answer (score 2):

The code works as written in the tutorial. However, there is a typo in your version of it. `module.export` should be `module.exports`. With this change it works as you hoped it would.

It would be good if Apostrophe noticed the absence of an export from a module's index.js file and flagged it with an error or at least a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I worked that out yesterday after tearing my hair out for an hour or so! Great service so far :-)